Nabla symbol with respect to different metrics
Suppose one has two Riemannian manifolds $(M, g)$ and $(N, h)$. Is there any convention or customary use regarding the notation of the connection with respect to these two different metrics, say e.g. $\nabla_g$ and $\nabla_h$, respectively? I find the notation used here as an example unpractical because if one wants to switch to index notation, then the $g$ and $h$ are a bit "in the way".
Please note, that this question is not about suggestions on how to write such expressions in a clear way, but rather on IF there is a customary way of distinguishing the connections of two different manifolds and IF SO, WHAT is the convention?

I've seen people writing it $\nabla^g$ (which allows for putting a vector field in, $\nabla^g_X$); I'm not saying that it's "the standard convention", but I met it and it was self-explanatory.

There’s no standard convention. Another way is to name one metric $g$ and the other $\tilde g$. The connections are then denoted $\nabla$ and $\widetilde\nabla$ respectively.
